# How can I change textfields layout in the vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, textfield, vuetify.js

I want to change the way textfields are laid out. My current markup reders like:

[image: image1]

I wan the layout to be redered like this :

[image: image2]

My code so far:

```html
<template>
    <v-card
        max-width="1200"
        class="mx-auto"
    >
      <v-container
        class="pa-2"
        fluid
      >
        <v-form
            ref="form"
            v-model="valid"
            lazy-validation
        >
            <v-text-field
            v-model="name"
            :counter="10"
            :rules="nameRules"
            label="Name"
            required
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            :rules="emailRules"
            label="E-mail"
            required
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

The result like this :

I want to change the result to be like this :

Comment: I think you need something like this: https://codepen.io/AnotherLinuxUser/pen/XZBKJP

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `outlined` property to havethe text fields displayed with the border.

See the [examples here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#examples)